# How to compare date with string in Linq with MVC4?

Tags: c#, jquery, linq, date

Hi I am developing one MVC$ application. I came across one query. In one of my database table I have datetime column. I will be storing data as below in that column.

```
Eg: 2016-10-05 11:57:54.650
```

I have one jquery calender where i will receive date as string. I will receive in the below format.

```
eg: 06/10/2016
```

I have below Linq query where I am comparing my jquery date with database date as below.
Below code I have tried so far.

```
   string datemodified;
   DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(datemodified);
   upld_id = (from c in db.upldTable where c.upld_clientid==clientId && EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.upld_ModifiedDateTime) == dt select c.upld_docid).ToArray();
```

My query does not work fine. My query not returning expected result. I am having problem in comparing date portion. If i did not compare date then my query works as expected. So I am sure my date comparision is not happening above. Can someone help me in this regard? Thanks a lot.

Comment: depending on your server settings in the app (and maybe in SQL Server too) 06/10/2016 could be interpreted as 6th October or 10th June. Check your localisation settings would be the first thing to do.

Comment: My string is not converting into dateformat in below line. DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(datemodified);

Comment: "not converting". So what happens instead? Do you get an error?

Comment: please add an example of the string you're trying to parse and the execption/error your getting. notice that: Convert.ToDateTime(datemodified) uses:DateTime.Parse(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) behind the scenes, this require a specific format to succeed!

Comment: 06/10/2016 this is the string format I am trying to convert it to date.